# Dijkstra Algorithm recovery from long dead ends behaviour

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I would like to reference this question: [Is Dijkstra's algorithm possible with graphs containing dead ends?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161933/is-dijkstras-algorithm-possible-with-graphs-containing-dead-ends)

It is somewhat similar however i need to know the Dijkstra behaviour if the dead end is many nodes on from a single edge i.e see the image link below

If the travel of minimal distance calculations continues down the direction as indicated by the arrow until it reaches the dead end, will a simple version of Dijkstra be able to recover and at what point if any will it not be able to recover, to back track through many edges to begin the correct route again?

I hope this makes sense and someone can help me understand this. Thank you. If you need any more information please ask.

[Dijkstra Example illustration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaZNj.png)

Comment: Yes, the normal version of dijkstra can handle this. If it reaches a dead end (I.e. it’s taken off the heap) no new adjacent vertices will be put in the heap, and it will just move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dijkstra's Algorithm is basically Dynamic Programming. The process reduces the dimension by one each step. After updating the current shortest distances, the next closed node is the one with the shortest distance. It will end up with finding the shortest distances from the origin to all other nodes. It doesn't have any issue such as dead end. If the graph has n nodes, it has to go through n steps (including the initialization step).

Of course, in your example, in case you only care about the shortest distance between the source and node $G$, you might end up with reaching $G$ before reaching the end of the long path. However, this doesn't mean Dijkstra's Algorithm fails. You need to work through a couple of examples. Once you fully understand it, you will get it.